# Nodejs took too long to respond

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, socket.io, redhat

I've moved my NodeJS application to a new server and am now having problems with listening on the same port. I have opened the port via iptables and the nodeJS application runs without errors in the terminal.

Here is the index.js code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  //Rooms
  socket.on('create-room', function (room) {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log('client joined room: ' + room);
    });

   socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
   socket.on('CB_Data', function(msg){
    console.log('JSON Message: ' + msg);
    var par = JSON.parse(msg);
    var stringArray = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < par.length; i++ ) {
        if ( typeof par[i] == "string" ) {
            stringArray.push(par[i]);
        }
    }

    console.log('Emit message "' + stringArray[1] + '" to room "' + stringArray[0] + '"');
    socket.broadcast.to(stringArray[0]).emit('CB_Data', stringArray[1]);

  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

When trying to visit the port via http://nawd.xyz:3000 I get the following error:

> nawd.xyz took too long to respond.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

As suggested by Pedro I have added the console.log code to the app.get function. It isn't fired when visiting from a browser however is fried when using the wget command from terminal on the server. Here is the response from the wget command:

> --2016-04-07 09:31:05--  http://localhost:3000/
>
> Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
>
> Connecting to localhost|::1|:3000... failed: Connection refused.
>
> Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:3000... connected.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>
> Length: 1211 (1.2K) [text/html]
>
> Saving to: `index.html'
>
> 100%[======================================>] 1,211       --.-K/s   in 0s
>
> 2016-04-07 09:31:05 (261 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [1211/1211]

These are my iptable rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Apr  7 12:39:01 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [330122:24332313]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [183017:13080114]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [183017:13080114]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Apr  7 12:39:01 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Apr  7 12:39:01 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2085:2522977]
:acctboth - [0:0]
:cP-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
:cphulk - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j cphulk 
-A INPUT -j cP-Firewall-1-INPUT 
-A INPUT -j acctboth 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 48000:48030 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 48000:48003 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 225 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 37 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 43 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 783 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 783 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 873 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 873 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1500 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1581 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1580 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2123 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2124 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2077 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 2077 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2078 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 2078 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2082 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2083 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2086 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2087 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2089 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2095 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2096 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j cP-Firewall-1-INPUT 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A OUTPUT -j acctboth 
-A acctboth -s 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 83.222.242.109/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.150/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.151/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.152/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.153/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.154/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.155/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.156/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.157/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.158/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.159/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.160/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.161/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.162/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 159.100.132.163/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.77/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 185.33.6.76/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth ! -i lo 
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 26 -j ACCEPT 
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT 
-A cP-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT 
-A cphulk -s 120.27.111.3/32 -m state --state NEW -m time --datestop 2016-04-07T12:29:15 --utc -j DROP 
-A cphulk -s 123.57.249.157/32 -m state --state NEW -m time --datestop 2016-04-07T12:36:07 --utc -j DROP 
-A cphulk -s 120.27.111.3/32 -m state --state NEW -m time --datestop 2016-04-07T12:44:26 --utc -j DROP 
-A cphulk -s 85.194.242.35/32 -m state --state NEW -m time --datestop 2016-04-07T12:53:49 --utc -j DROP 
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Apr  7 12:39:01 2016
```

Comment: Please also put the tag to Google chrome, often Opera, Firefox, Google Chrome causing it itself. I think you have to involve Google chrome/Chromium community for such issues.

Comment: Put a console.log in your app.get function to make sure that's firing. Also, try `wget localhost:3000` when you're logged in to your server to see if it's a nodejs problem or a connectivity problem.

Comment: The connection timeout may have a lot of reason, not just the server. It's possible that the connection is not established at all. As pedro said, do a console log to check the state of connection.

Comment: Updated my answer in response

Comment: Ok this suggests nodejs is fine and is serving web requests locally, but for some reason itbcant talk out to the internet. Please post your iptables / firewall rules.

Comment: I have updated my answer with my iptables

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the exact same issue, and the below is what fixed the issue for me!

Execute this

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 3000
```

and try hitting http://nawd.xyz